# Store ckc key data of AVURLAsset without play video

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, fairplay

I want to call programmatically the

```
func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool
```

of an `AVURLAsset` from the delegate of the `AVPlayer`, `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`, so that I can cash the ckc Data so that I can play decrypted content offline.

I followed the steps of https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/504/

If I play the `AVURLAsset` cash the ckc key data and then close the internet and play the `AVURLAsset` again it works and I can see the video offline.

But I need to call the `resourseLoader` function without to play the video.

The reason I can't do the steps is because to get the ckc data I need the `loadingRequest` object from the delegate function **`resourceLoader`**.

Is there any way to accomplish that without call the play method and discard player when I store the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe to late for you, I had the same problem. Try set add **preloadEligibleContentKeys** to **true** to your resource loader when you download.

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)        
// ADD THIS  LINE TO PRELOAD BEFORE PLAYING
asset.resourceLoader.preloadsEligibleContentKeys = true
asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

let downloadTask = downloadSession?.makeAssetDownloadTask(asset: asset, assetTitle: "Asset title", assetArtworkData: nil, options: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's never late for a refactor